# Cauchy schwarz inequality for inner product proof understanding

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products

I have the Cauchy Schwarz inequality for inner product is 
$$|<x,y>| \leq ||x||  ||y||$$ for $x , y \in X$

I have a part of the proof. 
We first assume that x and y are linearly dependant so we let $x=\alpha y$ and $\alpha \in K$ where K is either real or complex.

So we have $|<x,y>|= |<x,y>|= |\alpha| ||y||^2=\sqrt {\alpha \bar\alpha <y,y>} ||y|| = \sqrt{<\alpha y ,\alpha y>} ||y||=||x|| ||y||$

What does $\alpha \bar \alpha$ mean?

And how do you get from $\sqrt {\alpha \bar\alpha <y,y>} ||y||$ to $\sqrt{<\alpha y ,\alpha y>} ||y||$?

Comment: $\alpha\overline{\alpha}$ means the product of $\alpha$ and the conjugate of $\alpha$. The step you are wondering about is using that the inner product is a [sesquilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form), so linear in the first component and antilinear in the second.

Comment: (In case you didn't understand Your Ad Here) $a\bar a <y,y>=a <y,\bar a y>=<a y,\bar a y>$